# What is the meaning of this error?

Tags: r

Code:

```
pvalue <- matrix(nrow = 9, ncol = 10000)

for(i in 1:9) {
   for(j in 1:10000) {
    pvalue[i,j]=integrate(dnorm,0,1)    
   }
}
```

Error:

```
Error in pvalue[i, j] <- integrate(dnorm, 0, 1) : number of items to
replace is not a multiple of replacement length`
```

Comment: Why are you trying to integrate the density function when R offers the CDF?

Comment: the error is because `length(integrate(dnorm, 0, 1))` is 5 and `length(pvalue[i, j])` is 1.  you're trying to put a 5 long peg into a 1 long hole

Answer (score 1):

The output of the `integrate(dnorm,0,1)` is a list, not a number.

```
str(integrate(dnorm,0,1))

List of 5
 $ value       : num 0.341
 $ abs.error   : num 3.79e-15
 $ subdivisions: int 1
 $ message     : chr "OK"
 $ call        : language integrate(f = dnorm, lower = 0, upper = 1)
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "integrate"
```

A working code is:

```
pvalue <- matrix(nrow = 9, ncol = 10000)

for(i in 1:9) {
   for(j in 1:10000) {
    pvalue[i,j] <- integrate(dnorm,0,1)$value    
   }
}
```